# Rake doesn't find '*.rake' file in 'lib/tasks' directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a `foo.rake` file in `lib/tasks` directory of a Rails project.

```
namespace :foo do
  desc 'rake task example'
  def bar
    p "foo bar"
  end
end
```

But the `rake` command can't find the task, the following command outputs nothing.

```
bundle exec rake -T -A | grep foo
```

How can I run a rake task from command line?

Comment: In case anybody ends up here who is *not* using Rails: put your `.rake` files in a directory called `rakelib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rake tasks are defined like so:

```
namespace :foo do
  desc 'rake task example'
  task :bar do
    # Your code here
  end
end
```

Notice `task :bar do` instead of a usual method definition style `def bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```rb
Rake.add_rakelib('lib/tasks')
```

to your `Rakefile`.